# Mobile Portlet installation on websphere portal server

Tags: websphere-portal

I want to deploy my Mobile Portlet on mobile browser simulator using WebSphere Portal Server.

Whenever I launch the mobile browser simulator to run the application it gives following error:

```
SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle /_MobileBrowserSimulator/index.html has not been defined.

SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle localhost:10039 has not been defined.

IBM WebSphere Application Server
```

I have searched and found that this problem is coming.  I don't have `_mobileBorwserSimulator` ear file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `_MobileBrowserSimulator` is your ear file. Is it working when you access it from Browser (without any mobile user agent)? Which one did you install? Is it Mobile Portal Accelerator?

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. The topic has been closed, i didn't see your post, but yes thanks for your reply.